# kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput;The extension is not showing an control to upload neither the chosen photo

Tags: php, yii2

I follow everything that is said in the implementation article but when the form is being loaded it is not showing preview area and the chosen image but when the view that contain the widget is not rendered in main layout(rendered alone) It showing the control but very big,images are attached).here is what I did:

In the Controller:

```html
 public function actionProfilephoto($user_id,$titre=null){

 $model = \Yii::createObject(Profile::className());
 $model->scenario='photo';
 if(\Yii::$app->request->post() && $titre==null){
     $model=\Yii::$app->request->post('uploadExtraData')['user_id'];
     $model->photo = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');
     \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
     if($model->validate()){
        $reponses[]= $model->upload();
          if($reponses['error']==true){
             $reponse['error']=\Yii::t('app','An error occurs while uploading,Try again.') . ' ' . $reponses['erreur'] ; 
          }
     }else{
         $reponse['error']=\Yii::t('app','An error occurs while uploading,Try again.') . ' ' . implode(' ',$model->errors) ; 
     }
      $reponse['initialPreview'] = '<img src="'. \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['@webroot/media/utilisateurs/'. $model->lienphoto]) .'" class="file-preview-image" alt="" title="Desert">';
      $reponse['initialPreviewConfig']=['caption'=>\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['@webroot/media/utilisateurs/'. $model->lienphoto]),
                'width'=>'90px','url'=>\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['utilisateur/deletephoto'])];
      echo json_encode($reponse);
        \Yii::$app->end();
 }
return $this->render('profilephoto',array('model'=>$model,'titre'=>false,'ajax'=>false));
```

In view

```html
<div id="okp" class="panel panel-default center-block">
            <?php if($titre==true){
             echo '<p class="well-sm">';
           $this->render('/_alert', ['module' => $module,]);
            echo '</p>';}?>
            
            <h3 class="panel-title panel-heading text-center" style="margin-bottom:5px;"><strong><?= Html::encode($this->title)?></strong></h3>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                     'id'=> 'profile-form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation'   => true,
                    'enableClientValidation' => false
                ,'options'=>['class'=>'well-sm',
                    'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<?=FileInput::widget([
    'name' => 'photo',
    'language'=>\Yii::$app->language,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'uploadUrl'=>\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['settings/profilephoto']),
        'initialPreview'=> ['<img src="'. \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['@webroot/media/utilisateurs/'. $model->lienphoto]) .'" class="file-preview-image" alt="" title="Desert">'],
        'initialPreviewConfig'=> ['caption'=>\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['@webroot/media/utilisateurs/'. $model->lienphoto]),
                    'width'=>'90px',
        'url'=>\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['settings/deletephoto']),
        ],
        'uploadExtraData'=>['user_id'=>$model->user_id],
        'image'=>['width'=>'90px','height'=>'90px'],
        'allowedPreviewTypes'=>['image'],
        'allowedFileExtensions'=>['gif','png','jpeg','jpg'],
        'allowedFileTypes'=>['image'],
        'maxFileSize'=>'3072',
        'maxFileCount'=>'1',
        'validateInitialCount'=>true,
        'resizeImage'=>true,
        'maxImageWidth'=> 90,
        'maxImageHeight'=>90,
        'resizePreference'=>'width',
        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-success',
        'uploadClass' => 'btn btn-info',
        'removeClass' => 'btn btn-danger',
        'uploadIcon'=>'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i> ',
        'removeIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> ',
        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
        'browseLabel' =>  \Yii::t('app','Select Photo')
    ],
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*']
]);
?></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you also using Jasny Bootstrap?

Comment: How can I check which Bootstrap I am using?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed [this Bootstrap extension](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/)? I guess not. But if you have, then Jasny Bootstrap might conflict with Kartik's file input widget, since as far as I know, Kartik's widget is based on Jasny's file input.

Comment: NO I didn't install I am using the one that came with Yii

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue too, and its resolved by stop rendering this file from Yii2:

" bootstrap-fileinput.js ", remove it and the js conflict will be gone away and all activity will work fine.

Good luck.